# Obtener el nombre del día de una fecha en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la fecha 2019-01-08 00:00:00 y necesito obtener el nombre del día, en este caso el nombre debería de ser Martes.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hacer?

Comment: Use la función `DATENAME()` pero me arroja números y no el nombre

Comment: Pues @JaimeAtriano te acaba de responder. Si es correcta su respuesta la puedes marcar como válida. Recuerda que el nombre del día que devuelva va a depender del idioma en el que esté configurada la base de datos. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la funcion DateName

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2019-01-08 00:00:00')
```

Para que te lo muestre en español

```
SELECT (CASE DATENAME(dw,'2019-01-08 00:00:00')
     when 'Monday' then 'LUNES'
     when 'Tuesday' then 'MARTES'
     when 'Wednesday' then 'MIERCOLES'
     when 'Thursday' then 'JUEVES'
     when 'Friday' then 'VIERNES'
     when 'Saturday' then 'SABADO'
     when 'Sunday' then 'DOMINGO'
END)
```

Te dejo en un link donde puedes consultar mas acerca del uso del [DATENAME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma podrías obtener el nombre del día de la semana pero lo devolvería en inglés.

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday, '2019-01-08 00:00:00') AS nombreDiaSemana;
```

Por lo tanto, lo más recomendable sería traer el número del día de la semana y mediante el uso de casos ir determinando el nombre del día de la semana.

```
SELECT (case DATEPART(dw,'2019-01-08 00:00:00') when 2 then 'Lunes' when 3 then 'Martes' when 4 then 'Miércoles' when 5 then 'Jueves' when 6 then 'Viernes' when 7 then 'Sábado' when 1 then 'Domingo' end) AS nombreDiaSemana;
```

Nota:

- weekday - Devuelve el nombre del día de la semana.
- dw - Devuelve el número del día de la semana (puede ser del 1 al 7).

El número del día de la semana corresponde a lo siguiente:

- 1 - Domingo
- 2 - Lunes
- 3 - Martes
- 4 - Miércoles
- 5 - Jueves
- 6 - Viernes
- 7 - Sábado

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si se ha establecido un día de inicio de semana diferente usando `SET DATEFIRST`? Me parece que haría falta una comprobación previa. Puedes ver [Argumentos de DATEPART - Semana y dia de semana](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments) para una idea de lo que digo. Saludos